# How much percentage royalty do I get from Springer (as the paper's author) and how I can apply for royalty payment?

Tags: publications, research-process, publishers, springer

I have submitted a paper to a Springer conference and it has been published. The publisher will charge 24.95$ to anyone who would eventually download my paper and 201 copies of my research sold by Springer official site.

**How much percentage royalty do I get from Springer (as the paper's author) and how I can apply for royalty payment?**

Comment: I would be extremely impressed if they actually sold 201 copies of a paper for $24.95 each, it would imply your paper is truly groundbreaking.

Comment: Also, if you want royalties, you need to negotiate *before* your paper is published.

Comment: The others have already mentioned that you get nothing. Also I think the site shows the number of downloads, and not necessarily the number of people who purchased the chapter.

Comment: Sold or accessed? Oftentimes those who read a paper are part of a university that has paid access to entire journals through a subscription.

Comment: @Allure, do you know of any publisher/conference that will actually pay royalties on papers, under any circumstances?

Comment: Just complementing @Allure's comment. A researcher most probably has (virtual) access to a paper via a library (e.g., in a university) and the library pays the publisher to have access to a huge set of papers at once (just like people don't pay for each movie on netflix). Sometimes it is also possible to download legally and for free "pre-print" or "full" versions of a paper that are actually almost identical to the paper sold by the publisher. Not to mention sites like sci-hub, where one finds a ton of papers... So usually people don't pay for a specific paper as you implied in your question.

Comment: The fact that Springer profits from your work and you don't is yet another excellent reason to avoid commercial publishers altogether. I prefer to work with academic publishers and publications of professional societies; at least if they make money, it goes back into the discipline.

Comment: @Buffy in the sense of royalties as a percentage of revenue? No, I am not aware of any. Even for review volumes (where there is a more explicit negotiation prior to publication), the chapter authors usually do not get such royalties, although the editors usually do, and the chapter authors get other forms of remuneration (typically free books and discounts on other purchases from the publisher).

Comment: @Buffy there is this though: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63619/how-much-revenue-do-academic-authors-make-on-their-published-books/135554#comment152700_63631 One would have to ask Bob Brown for details (it's apparently not a journal/conference paper in any case, although one could arguably say it's a chapter in a conference proceedings).

Comment: @Allure, yes, but, as you note, that is a chapter in a book, not a paper or a conference proceeding. Royalties are normally paid for books and in Prof Brown's case, it may have been by invitation.

Comment: @GregMartin: The one ("professional societies") does not necessarily preclude the other ("commercial publishers"). A journal may be published by a commercial publisher on behalf of a society, which then gets paid. (Since journals are sold to libraries in packages, the precise distribution of the income is an art.) Case in point: the [*International Journal of Forecasting*](https://forecasters.org/ijf/), published by Elsevier on behalf of the International Institute of Forecasters.

Comment: BTW depends on your Country of origin, as an author you might be able to get royalties from your local societies, for example in Germany, you would get member of vgwort: https://www.vgwort.de/verguetungen/auszahlungen/wissenschaftliche-publikationen.html

Comment: Sounds like something that should be asked to the publisher directly

Comment: @GregMartin not beeing paid is not limited to commercial publishers, and in fact it’s not the worst thing, it’s mich worse if you have to pay a fee for being reviewed or published.

Comment: To collect royalties from Springer, you have to write a successful book.  A paper for a conference, nothing.  Same for all publishers, big or small, for-profit or non-profit.

Answer (score 254):

**You get nothing: Welcome to academic publishing.**

Comment: The OP won't get money. But, they get fame which is not nothing.

Comment: @scaaahu Indeed. But, the question asks about royalties.

Comment: Isn't academic publishing great?! /s

Comment: @JSLavertu Enriching

Comment: Publishers, including Springer, pay royalties on books, not on papers, and the details are worked out in a contract prior to publishing and prior to copyright transfer. Actually, for some authors, the exact copyright terms might be negotiable also. But this is only for books.

Comment: @scaaahu I like your comment, and it reminds me of a quote from "The Sound of Music"... where a promoter is discussing their plans to make a singing group famous ... "They get fame, you get money."  "It's unfair, I admit it. But someday that'll be changed. I shall get the fame too."

Comment: *"You lose! Good day, sir!"*

Comment: They get to keep their job, which pays money, so indirectly they get money.

Comment: @user2768 the only royalty here is the guy who gets the business class ticket and hotel paid by Springer, and that’s rarely an author.

Comment: @scaaahu Exposure is something you die of

Comment: Actually you do get visibility, cite-ability and peer review. Compared to predatory publishers who will ask you to pay a commercial publisher like springer is not so bad after all. Not to mention recognition at your local institution with potential bonus or career benefits from being published.

Comment: @eckes Yes, but the question explicitly asks about royalties.

Answer (score 88):

You get absolutely nothing.

When you submitted the paper to the conference, you (very much likely) transferred the copyright of your paper to the publisher retaining just a couple of rights, but not that of being paid by the publisher.

Comment: Depending on where you are, you can get *some* money. Just not from the publisher. In Germany you can register with VG WORT to receive some money that is collected from libraries as well as printer/copy machine sales in exchange for it being legal to copy arbitrary copyrighted works.

Comment: As a point of reference, for a single ~30 page paper VG WORT paid about 240€ for the year 2019. This gets divided by the number of authors, whether they actually receive anything from VG WORT or not.

Comment: @Maeher It's nice to receive at least some money but compared to the publisher's profit margin it's laughable. Also, VG WORT only pays for journals that are still published in print. These are becoming rare.

Comment: @Roland Really, I was thinking online only publications also count (-> METIS). Thats why they have web counters.

Comment: @Roland I mean the profit *margin* is close to 100%, given that there are virtually no costs involved. I don't think their absolute profit *per paper* is all that impressive. They just publish lots of papers.

Comment: @AndreasH. Theoretically, yes. However the publisher would need to include those counters and at least Springer does not. (Since VG WORT was sued a few years back for giving part of the money to publishers instead of authors, they pretty much have nothing to gain from doing so either.)

Comment: @Maeher The profit margins are more in the 35% range: see https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/jun/27/profitable-business-scientific-publishing-bad-for-science  There is staff to pay, and investment needed to keep the technology going.  Springer doesn't invest much in the back-end and their author experience is not great.  At least Elsevier does invest in technology and their journals are run much more efficiently.  35% is still quite a good (almost predatory) margin...

Answer (score 31):

Here's how academic publishing works.

- You write the paper. Your peers review it for free. The journal charges people to read the paper to cover copy-editing/hosting costs, and to make a profit.
- You write a paper. Your peers review it for free. The journal charges *you* to cover copy-editing/hosting costs, and to make a profit, then gives it away for free.

Unfortunately you're not allowed to save money by doing the copy-editing yourself, nor are you allowed to use your institution's infrastructure for hosting. You can't submit to a university-run committee to organise the peer review.

To be taken seriously you have to publish in the well-known and established journals of your field. To publish in those journals you (or the tax-payer or funder) have to contribute to the publisher's profits.

To answer your question more directly, they won't be giving any of those profits to you.

Edit: forgot to say, for anyone who can't afford to pay for scientific articles (or who wants to make a point), you can access the majority via Sci-Hub.

Comment: There are a few truly open access journals where neither you, your institution, libraries, or the readers pay for accessing journals, but they are sadly not common enough. Everyone should do all they can to support them though!

Comment: @curiousdannii How do those journals pay for operating costs?

Comment: Some (open access) journals issue vouchers to reviewers, that can be redeemed to reduce publication fees.

Comment: @gerrit from external funding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access#Diamond/platinum_OA). There's no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: ["_Business Model_"](https://arxiv.org/about/reports-financials), arXiv, currently shows their 2020 financials.  They claim 1,960,442 USD in both revenue and direct-expenses (which balance out to zero).  Apparently the costs exclude support contributed by Cornell (which they cite at 723,670 USD) and the value of volunteers' time (which they don't price).

Comment: "by doing the copy-editing yourself" - this may be field dependent, but in some fields, the author indeed does most of the copy-editing (which does not prevent publishers from charging the described costs all the same).

Comment: @gerrit External funding, but since copy-editing in papers is negligible, hosting doubly so, the cost is rather minimal.

Comment: note that scihub is not legal, but with the profit margins journals must have (and the tax-payer funding most research has) I would hesitate to say whether it is immoral or unethical to use scihub.

Comment: @TheV Some would even say that publishing in most academic journals (those that profit from free work of others) is immoral and unethical ;-)