# Chances of academically publishing a book without professional degree

Tags: publications, books, springer

I have been considering publishing the book I am writing with [Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp); specifically under the series Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics (or any related series). I believe the contents of the book would be a great addition to the related content published by Springer and I also believe it would be popular amongst both mathematicians and physicists. The issue [I believe I face] is that I lack a degree. The contents of the book do not necessarily warrant a degree, for the book is mostly on special functions and their employment. I should also mention that the book is about 90% complete (perhaps this increases my chances of publication?).

[This](https://www.springer.com/gp/campaign/chemistry-book-3) page is what I am most concerned about. I fail to be able to fill out the "Affiliation" and "Personal website" sections, for I have neither; i.e., I lack a degree and a website. Now for the question:

**Will lacking a degree in mathematics or physics prevent my book from being published?**

And a follow up:

**Would "hobbyist" be an appropriate title for the section labeled "Title"?**

I am asking such questions to gauge whether or not I should even submit my proposal. Thank you!

Comment: No idea for the main question, but for your follow-up I would suggest "Independent Scholar".

Comment: Do not expect to earn money this way.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/how-much-do-springer-verlag-authors-make-per-book-sold/32107#32107

Comment: My two cents: In addition, Springer wants their books to sell. And many books in academic sells as course literature. If you can show that a book will fit well as material in a course it enhances the possibilities for it to be published.

Comment: "Affiliation" is not about having a degree, it is about having a job. This is where you fill out your employer. And the "Title/Profession" part is where you fill out what you do at that employer. The form does not ask about a degree at all.

Comment: A bit on the side: try to find one or two theoretical physicists or mathematician (although I doubt there are a lot left interested in special functions, maybe in Russia, maybe in numerical math), who read your draft.

Comment: A bit tangential, but I think it's worth reading Robert Ghrist's [explanation](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/whyselfpublish.html) of why he (a tenured professor at a major research university) self-published his book.

Comment: @korrok The main issue I see with self-publishing my book is the difficulty in making it known. I have no way of doing this, and thus find it very unlikely anyone will ever see my book. Perhaps I am ignorant as to certain programs or techniques one can use to make a self-published book more known; I will look further into it if things do not pan out with Springer. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whether Springer or any other publisher wants to publish any given book is entirely up to them. I'm sure that plenty of books are published by people without degrees.

But note that first you need to attract an "acquisitions editor" who makes a preliminary determination whether it is worth their time to work with you. Convince them that you have the necessary background and writing skill: perhaps with a sample chapter. One determination is whether the material "fits" into what they think of as good things to be associated with.

Once you get into the system, your manuscript will almost certainly be sent to a few "reviewers" who will make comments on what you write and make a recommendation to the editor. If their judgments are favorable, then you will probably get published. But expect several rounds of review and re-edit before you get to the production phase.

As to your personal title, you can simply say *independent researcher*, which is probably better than hobbyist, assuming that you need any "title" at all.

But before you bother to submit anything, spend some time trying to understand the sorts of things they like to publish in your field.

Comment: _you can simply say independent researcher_ you mean assuming that that’s a true fact, right? OP did not say anything about being a researcher.

Comment: @DanRomik, when I read *independent researcher* it could be anything from a full-time researcher outside of a university to someone doing it part-time beside "normal" work. I don't expect them to stand in a laboratory all day and earn their main income by that.  I think the expectations behind that formulation might differ, but I would suppose that it describes his role/position as close as possible.

Comment: @Cribber I believe Dan's point is that OP didn't specify that they are a researecher at all, whether full-time or part-time.

Comment: Hmmm, @DanRomik, why do you think that a person who reads and thinks and writes mathematics (and physics) isn't  a _researcher_? Is there a special handshake?

Comment: @Buffy someone who is writing a math textbook isn’t by definition a researcher, and even someone who “reads and thinks and writes mathematics” isn’t automatically a researcher (that definition would make all students of math anywhere researchers, and strip the word of any useful meaning). To be a researcher you have to at least dabble in research. There isn’t a special handshake, and anyone can be a researcher if they want to, but nonetheless not everyone is, and I wouldn’t advise OP to represent himself as one if he isn’t.

Comment: “*Independent mathematician*” would do.  The competent creation of non-research textbooks is not limited to researchers.  Honestly, I don’t even know where the bias towards such a presumption comes from, though I suspect that it explains where many bad textbooks have come from.  Clearly teaching is a more relevant background for textbook creation than research is.

Comment: @DanRomik you are putting far too much stock into the word researcher. There are no well defined properties for the title.

Comment: @RBarryYoung On the other hand, I would certainly not use the term "mathematician" without having done serious amounts of work in math, as it has far more connotations than the word researcher.  You would probably have most people laughing at you if you claimed to be a mathematician without undergrad and graduate work in topic, or a published paper in a real journal.

Answer (score 21):

As someone who has served as referee for math textbook proposals for reputed academic publishers, I can tell you that if your proposal were sent to me, I could not care less about whether you have a degree or what your title is. I would care about the content of your proposal and whether it convinced me that you can write a high quality, correct, and interesting book that serves a need for students and researchers of mathematics.

**However**. You should have no illusions that convincing me of such a thing is an easy standard to meet. It’s not. It wouldn’t be easy even for a professional mathematician with many publications under their belt, and I would expect that it would be doubly difficult for someone who doesn’t have formal training in mathematics at a level equivalent to at least a PhD, let alone an undergraduate degree.

But as I said, the lack of a degree by itself would not be a problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

> Will lacking a degree in mathematics or physics prevent my book from being published?

It won't outright *prevent* your book from being published, but it will be a disadvantage. This stems from two things:

1. Without a degree, unless you can demonstrate exceptional achievement, you are less of an authority.
2. Without a degree, like it or not, your books will simply sell less. By extension, that means they're less profitable.

One can complain about these being unfair, of course, but the fact remains that given two books on chess theory, one written by a former world champion and the other written by an amateur nobody has heard of, it's practically guaranteed that the first book will sell much better regardless of content.

That said, not having a degree does not disqualify your book from being published. That still comes down to the publisher. Things they might take into account include "can I expect this book to sell regardless?", or "how much will it cost us to publish this manuscript", or even "do I need to maintain good relations with this author?" (if you can potentially publish more projects with them).

Since your manuscript is already mostly written, you have nothing to lose by contacting Springer. I would suggest doing it. Sample chapters accelerate the pace at which they can come to a decision as well.

> Would "hobbyist" be an appropriate title for the section labeled "Title"?

No, use Mr., Mrs., or Ms. as applicable (along with your profession).

Comment: "Without a degree, like it or not, your books will simply sell less."  Implausible.  Most purchases by academic libraries are (or were, before they stopped buying anything) standing orders of all books in a certain category.  Individual buyers are unlikely to check the author bio before ordering.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist ?!? I cannot imagine any library having a contract with Springer or anyone to buy one of each book they publish. 90% of them would vanish in the archive without ever being read. And individuals buy upon recommendation. The author affiliation and bio is certainly part of that.

Comment: "90% of them would vanish in the archive without ever being read."  @Karl What makes you think that does not happen?  Some libraries have a lot of books.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_largest_libraries_in_the_United_States#Largest_research_libraries

Comment: I did not claim they buy every book published.  Just the books within a certain category.

Comment: @Karl don't worry about it really. People who've worked at publishers/libraries know just how many libraries buy every book published by a publisher, including in a certain category. AP almost surely does not.

Comment: Yea. That "every book in category" order sounds like it includes a bimonthly box of fine wine and two weekends at the beach in summer for the head of library and head of accounting.

Comment: By the way, if AP's view of academic publishing really is correct, publishers would regularly publish a few junk books just to reap the extra revenue. After all, they can publish junk and libraries would still buy them.

Comment: @ Allure: Perhaps it varies between fields. At least in my field (pure maths), my understanding from the librarians I’ve talked to agrees with @AnonymousPhysicist: A large proportion of acquisitions are books in specific “series” (e.g. Springer’s *Lecture Notes in Mathematics*, or the AMS Monographs series), and libraries subscribe to these series like they would subscribe to a journal.  These series are highly selective; the publishers’ incentive not to inflate them with junk is because that would damage their reputation and libraries would stop subscribing.

Comment: [cont’d] The other main category of acquisitions is books requested by faculty members. For this, the writer’s academic reputation will certainly help, as will their familiarity with the channels for publicising their book (conferences; journal book review columns; word of mouth…). But a degree, in itself, isn’t directly relevant at all — only to the extent that being an active researcher correlates strongly with having a degree.  If the OP is involved actively and competently in the field, most other researchers won’t care or even notice whether they have a degree.

Comment: "publishers would regularly publish a few junk books just to reap the extra revenue"  They probably do sometimes, but also in the current market they can get high quality books for very low royalties, which eliminates the motivation to publish junk.  The real issue today is that university presses are going out of business.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "publishing". If you want to make it publicly available, and touch as much people as possible with your book, publishing it by Springer is not always the best way to go.

As a personal experience, I'm writing [a math book](http://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/giulietta.pdf) while having no affiliation. The "originality" is to be completely free (the [LaTeX sources](https://github.com/LaurentClaessens/mazhe/) are licensed as GNU-FDL).

Once a year I make [a summary](https://linuxfr.org/news/le-frido-et-giulietta-la-mathematique-libre) of the news about the project on a well known french open source oriented website. This is sufficient to touch almost 100% of my potential lectors.

This way I do have some feedback and people is writing emails pointing some errors/typos/recommendations.

In some sense, if you publish your book by a commercial editor, you basically trash your work since it will loose the rights to keep the book available to the community after the editor decides to not print it anymore.

An other interesting point in publishing "the open source way" is that you keep your liberty of writing what you want with your own style. My book contains illustrations from [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/538/) which would be impossible to use in a commercial product.

Comment: It's not impossible to use xkcd in a commercial product - Randal Monroe seems relatively relaxed about (limited) use in books: https://xkcd.com/license.html. Good luck with your book - hope it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

*Will lacking a degree in mathematics or physics prevent my book from being published?*

No, but it would help if you show your work to established academics. If they like it, they may kindly say so to their Springer contact. (Almost every established academic has a Springer contact. They approach us as soon as they see we have not half-bad set of lecture notes online.) And then you are in.

*Would "hobbyist" be an appropriate title for the section labeled "Title"?*

No! You might as well write *crackpot*. Somebody else suggested *independent researcher*. I think that is a wonderful term in itself, but unfortunately it is tainted by the fact that this is how crackpots often refer to themselves. This is one instance where I would recommend a white lie, and say that you are working toward a BSc or MSc or PhD, whatever is appropriate in your position. (In fact, do put an application to a suitable school or college in the mail right now, so it is technically not even a lie.)